# Throwing temporary exceptions without "unreachable code detected"

Tags: c#, debugging, exception, unreachable-code

When writing code, I'll quite often temporarily inject random exceptions to ensure error flow is as expected.

eg

```
public void SomeFunc()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Some code");

   throw new Exception("BOOOOM!"); //added temporarily

   Console.WriteLine("Some more code");
}
```

The problem is I have warnings set as errors, so compilation will fail with a [CS0162 Unreachable code detected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0162), since "Some more code" will never run.

So just add a condition you say:

```
public void SomeFunc()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Some code");

   if (true)
       throw new Exception("BOOOOM!"); //added temporarily

   Console.WriteLine("Some more code");
}
```

but no, this compiler is clever enough to note that the condition will always be true, and flags a CS0162 again.

I generally end up with the following:

```
public void SomeFunc()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Some code");

   var debug = true;
   if (debug)
       throw new Exception("BOOOOM!"); //added temporarily

   Console.WriteLine("Some more code");
}
```

So my idle question, since I'm lazy, is whether there's a simpler way to fool the compiler? A one liner would be perfect.

(And yes, I do write unit tests eventually ;)

Comment: To fool the compiler, try computing some *method*, e.g. `if (Math.Abs(0) == 0) throw new NotImplementedException("BOOM!");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is rather dumb, in fact. It generally doesn't recognise non-[constant expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#constant-expressions). This means that you just need to create a condition that is always true, with at least one non-constant expression.

I'm sure that after reading the link, you can come up with *loads* of these. Here's an example:

```
if ("a".Length == 1) throw new Exception("...");
```

Comment: Thanks. `if (".".Any())` is the shortest I've come up with so far.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a two-liner. Resharper suggested and did this for me. Otherwise remembering it would be all but impossible.

```
    throw new Exception("Boo!");

#pragma warning disable 162

    // The unreachable code is here            

#pragma warning restore 162
```

While that's a direct answer, I probably wouldn't do that because it's clunky.

You can also change the severity of the error so that it compiles with a warning. That's my default setting.

The specifics of how to do that vary with the Visual Studio version. [Here's the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019).

In Visual Studio 2019 you would add or modify this in your .editorconfig file:

```
[*.cs]

# CS0162: Unreachable code detected
dotnet_diagnostic.CS0162.severity = warning
```

Comment: Ah! Didn't realise you could set individual severity at a global level. That's very useful thanks. That being said I'll probably leave it on since I do want to be informed about genuine cases.